# How to send key-ins to certain windows

Tags: java

I'm looking to write a relatively simple key macro for my own edification and also for my own use.

I intend for it to be able to run in the background when I run other programs, and at the press of a button will enter certain text into the active window. To be more specific, I want to go in a video game and use it to automatically send messages instead of having to type them.

I Googled around a bit, but apparently I'm not using the right keywords because I'm not really sure where to start. The closest I came was finding the Keystroke class, but that appears to be used for receiving keystrokes, not sending them.

I would appreciate and info regarding, or directing me to a resource for, these issues (how to send keystrokes to windows and anything about targeting which window etc).

Comment: Games usually have that. If not by design, at least by some plugin created by a third party (or gamers). I don't believe Java is the way here. Maybe http://www.autohotkey.com/ can help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending a keyboard event from java to any application (on-screen-keyboard)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156912/sending-a-keyboard-event-from-java-to-any-application-on-screen-keyboard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send key strokes you can use java.awt.Robot

To Choose which window to activate you can look around for ws script (windows script) or old VB6 code and use it to make VB script (simple text file of extn .vbs)

Or you can junk all that and use http://www.autohotkey.com/ which has window activation, sending keys, doing things on press of certain keys (like Windows Key + B) or macros.

---

To get a window to activate I had made an exe long back, but no longer use it, can get it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/win-utils/files/Window-Position/rel%2001/ (but only get this if the others do not work as need to seperately get COMCTL32.ocx and install that

---

If you do not want to use autohotkey you can use Jini to call platform specific functions, with a wrapper to call correst OSes functions. Never done it my self, when i had to use it i would make a process to call a exe that made the window come the front.

Comment: Thanks for the info about Robot.