# Simulate keypress in java to write user inputs to another application

Tags: java, awt, awtrobot, virtual-keyboard

I am developing a virtual keyboard application. Everything works fine except that what ever i write is written into the present application only not the one that is running behind.

I fell this is because ROBOT class in java only works for the application context that creates it.

Is there a work around for this?

Here is the code, i am trying to write **ls** in the terminal that is behind my java application:

```
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);

        robot.keyPress('l');
        robot.keyRelease('l');
        robot.keyPress('s');
        robot.keyRelease('s');

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: Is it something like this you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/q/156912/1310566

Answer (score 2):

judging from [this example](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-se-api-tutorials/59-how-sendkeys-application-java-using-robot-class.html), the `Robot` class is able to send keystrokes to external applications - but they will arrive at the `topmost window` so you basically need to focus the window to which you want to have your keystrokes sent, there seems to be a variety of solutions for this, im guessing this one is the easiest :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4782350/351861:

> Alternatively, you can write a VBScript to activate another
>   application. For example:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.AppActivate("Firefox")
```

> Then use Runtime.exec from your Java app to execute the script.

Comment: The example you mentioned works fine when i know what application will be next.But in my case i want to use this application as a replacement to normal physical keyboard.So i should be able navigate and type just like a normal keyboard.

Comment: in that case you wont need to anything and this question is void since a virtual keyboard does exactly that -- it sends keystrokes to the topmost application and nothing else. Btw : "what application will be next" doesnt make any sense. There is no "next" in operating systems of any kind, only Z-indexes of graphical windows, the one with the highest Z-value receives broadcasted events. Thats how modern operating systems work.